# Integration of twitter-like services (for example identi.ca) with FriendStream

Tags: friendstream

Is there an application that allows integrating identi.ca with FriendStream?  If no is there any docs how to integrate one (I know that second part is off-topic and probably should go on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/) but it is conditional)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I've been able to find.

Seesmic [can be configured to connect to StatusNet accounts](http://status.net/2010/03/25/using-seesmic-for-android-with-statusnet)

There is also a dedicated [StatusNet app for Android](http://status.net/wiki/Android_installation)

HootSuite does not currently support StatusNet accounts The online client can access statusNet via Ping.fm, but not android client.

I used the Seesmic app for a while, but now I'm using HootSuite and the StatusNet standalone client. At the time I switched, I thought I could configure HootSuite to do what I wanted. So it goes.....